# How to pass async function as parameter

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm using a function that extracts data from a GitHub repository.
It returns an object with metrics like the number of closed issues, etc.
This function is passed as a parameter of another function that stores these metrics in a database.

```
store(extract());
```

The problem is that the extract function is asynchronous (and for some reason, it needs to be asynchronous) and is not returning values...
I don't know how to manage async very well. How I force store() to wait for extract() return the metrics?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only deal with the Promise `extract` produces or make `store` asynchronous as well and use `await`. Which is basically the same thing, anyway, as `await` is still using the Promise.

Comment: `How I force store() to wait for extract() return the metrics?` --> `store(await extract())` if the containing function is async

Comment: How do I declare an export an async? Example: exports.extract = () => {}

Answer (score 17):

I ended up here trying to find a solution to a similar problem, so for other unlucky lads like me, gonna paste what I figured out, the following works:

```
async function A(B: () => Promise<void>) {
    await B();
}
```

Now I want to call `A` and pass an async function, then I do it like this:

```
await A(async () => {
    await wait(3000);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Async function is nothing but a function return promise. take sample.

```js
const getPromise = () =>  Promise.resolve("1")

const store = (fn) => {
  fn().then(console.log)
}
store(getPromise)

const storeCB = (fn, cb) => {
  fn().then(cb)
}
store(getPromise, console.log)

const storeThen = (fn) => {
  return fn().then(x => "append: " + x)
}
storeThen(getPromise).then(console.log)

const getAsync = async () =>  "2"

store(getAsync)


const storeWithAwait = async (fn) => {
  const restult = await fn()
  return restult
}

storeWithAwait(getAsync).then(console.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
(async ()=>{
   const result = await extract();
   store(result);
})()
```

Comment: Or `store(await extract())`.

Comment: How do I declare an export an async? Example: exports.extract = () => {}

Comment: if you only have 1 script to export then `export default async function(){}`, if you have more things to export then you can do it like this: first declare your function for example `async function myFunction(){}` then you can export it `export { myFunction };` and later you import it `import { myFunction } from "path/to/script"`

Answer (score 0):

Either use an async [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) like this:

```
(async () => {
   const result = await extract();
   store(result);
})();
```

Or use the classic syntax:

```
extract().then(store);
```

Comment: Or just `extract().then(store)`.

Comment: How do I declare an export an async? Example: exports.extract = () => {}